# Coin Change program in apex

Tags: apex, class

**Edit: Figured it out , thanks for help.**

```
public class coin
{
    public static Integer amounts(Integer[] coins, Integer amo)
    {
        Integer[] dp = new Integer[amo+1];
        for(Integer k = 0; k < dp.size(); k++)
        {
            dp[k] = amo+1;
        }
        dp[0] = 0;
        for(Integer i = 0; i <= amo; i++)
        {
            for(Integer j = 0; j < coins.size(); j++)
            {
                if(coins[j] <= i)
                {
                    dp[i] = math.min(dp[i],1+ dp[i - coins[j]]);
                }
            }
        }
        Integer inde = dp.size();
        system.debug('The smallest amount of coins to make up ' + amo + ' are ' + dp[inde - 1]);
        return dp[amo] > amo ? -1 : dp[amo];
    }
}
```

**Debug:
The smallest amount of coins to make up 59 are 8**

//////////////////////////////////

I've been trying to write a program in apex to find the smallest amount of coins to make up a certain amount(Coin Change problem).I've written a code from a java program I found on coin change problem.

```
public class coin
{
    public static Integer amounts(List<Integer> coins, Integer amo, Integer m)
    {
        Integer combi;
        for(Integer i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            Integer t = coins.get(i);
            if(t <= amo)
            {
                Integer smalcoin = amounts(coins, amo-t, m);
                combi = smalcoin;
            }
        }
        system.debug(combi);
        return combi;
    }
}

In Anonymous Window:
List<Integer> last = new List<Integer>{1,2,5,10};
coin.amounts(last,15,4);
```

The original java code works fine. But this one takes a lot of time to execute and doesn't give a clear output.

This is the original java code

```
class coin
{
    // m is size of coins array (number of different coins)
    static int minCoins(int coins[], int m, int V)
    {
    // base case
    if (V == 0) return 0;
    
    // Initialize result
    int res = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    
    // Try every coin that has smaller value than V
    for (int i=0; i<m; i++)
    {
        if (coins[i] <= V)
        {
            int sub_res = minCoins(coins, m, V-coins[i]);
    
            // Check for INT_MAX to avoid overflow and see if
            // result can minimized
            if (sub_res != Integer.MAX_VALUE && sub_res + 1 < res)
                res = sub_res + 1;
        }
    }
    return res;
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    int coins[] = {9, 6, 5, 1};
    int m = coins.length;
    int V = 11;
    System.out.println("Minimum coins required is "+ minCoins(coins, m, V) );
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be specific about the problem. It is normal for Apex to run much slower than Java. If you are not seeing the output you expect, show exactly what is output and describe how it differs from your expectations. See [ask] and [help/on-topic].

Comment: You should consider clearer variable names so your code is more legible.

Comment: The more I look at this algorithm, the less I like it. Doing a single subtraction and then calling the function to do the next one is bad enough, but this Java code that you're using is then going through the same process for _every other denomination_. The number of times it ends up calling `minCoins()` is something like 2^N (i.e. exponential time. Starting values of 11, 21, 31, and 41 cause the recursive function to be called 47; 1020; 21,819; and 465,934 times respectively. Got a CPU limit exception when I tried 51).

Comment: Answering your own question via `Answer` is more appropriate than editing your `Question` to include the solution.

Answer (score 2):

From a brief glance, it looks like the primary issue is that your `List<Integer> last` is initialized with the coins in the wrong order. (+edit: After more work, this isn't the issue. The algorithm in the question should be order-insensitive, albeit at a considerable cost to cpu time).

Thinking about the problem a little, the number of coins is minimized when you start with the largest denomination (+edit: not always, `{25, 15, 1}` and `30` fails with this greedy approach). The code that you've copied (translated from Java into Apex) starts working through the denomination starting at index 0 and continues on to index 1, 2, and so on. The way you initialize your list, you're starting with the *smallest* denomination.

If you take a little more of a look at the original Java version, you'll see `int coins[] = {9, 6, 5, 1};`. They start with the largest denomination at index 0. If you don't follow suit, of course your results will look odd (and be incorrect).

As Adrian noted, the variable names here could stand to be *drastically* improved. `V` is a terrible, non-descriptive variable name. If you see it in isolation, it gives little to no information about what it is. You (and everyone else) have to search for additional context to be able to make sense of it, and that increases the *mental load* to read and understand the code.

Naming things is one of the two hard problems in computer science (the others being cache invalidation, and off-by-one errors), but even something short like `givenValue` would be a large improvement.

For my final note, I'll say that while you *can* use recursion to solve this problem, I'm not sure if recursion offers any benefit here. A simple loop using integer division would likely be shorter and easier to read.

```java
// You don't need to write a for loop like for(Integer i = 0; i < coins.size(); i++)
//   in Apex.
// If you have a list, Apex offers a loop syntax to iterate through the elements
for(Integer denomination :coins){
    // integer division rounds down to the whole number
    Integer numOfDenomination = givenValue / denomination;
    numCoins += numOfDenomination;
    givenValue -= numOfDenomination * denomination;
}
```

Comment: The point of the algorithm, though, is to use or find the fewest coins. An example I found goes like: `coins = { 2, 3, 5, 6 }` and we want to find `9`. A greedy algorithm will find `{5, 2, 2}`, but the most efficient solution is `{ 3, 6 }`. Using a recursive strategy is helpful in finding the optimal solution(s).

Comment: @sfdcfox Do you have another example? Using a greedy algorithm on a sorted (descending) list of denominations yields a result of 2 coins for your input, and has much better performance (i.e. it doesn't go over the CPU limit for an input of `{25, 10, 5, 1}` and `51`)

Comment: The point of the Coin Change Problem is that the order can be arbitrary. Here's an example [Coin Change Problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/coin-change-dp-7/). The operating theory is that programmers should be able to write algorithms when the data being operated on is constrained in some way.

Comment: Also, thinking of it, it's a variant of the Travelling Salesman problem. You don't get to arrange the costs any way you want, you have to use the costs you're given.